How to rewrite a long URL to fix forwarding issue
I sent out some flyers with the url example.org/youth. Sadly, example.org resolves to https://www.example.org but example.org/youth resolves to a 404 error. How do I edit the .htaccess to make this work?
I should mention that the site is a google site.
I see this answer here and here, and I'm pretty sure that's what I need to do as well, but I don't sufficiently understand what they're doing to modify for my needs.

Please add your current configuration file to the question (the ".htaccess" file you refer to). How else do you expect us to tell you how you could modify it? Please add such information to the question itself, not in a comment. Thanks.

In general you need to understand that example.com and www.example.com are two completely separate things (hosts) from the point of view of the http server. Whether you can configure both hosts at once completely depends on your setup, which we know nothing about.
